# How do I create this type of view in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to experiment with swift and I was thinking of making something like the picture. But I can't figure out what views they are using. Can someone just explain if it is a collection view, table view or is it a collection view embedded in a table view?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fheOo.jpg)

Comment: It looks like a table view, with the cells containing collection views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be either a UICollectionView or UITableView, with UICollectionViews embedded in each cell.

A UITableView should be fine for the main container view, as it provides vertical scrolling, and then UICollectionViews can be used for the horizontally scrolling content in each cell.